# mother of pearl chop marks on underside of large ivory chess pieces (Characters identified: 乾隆年製)

Tags: translation, character-identification, seal

Large and very fine ivory chess set that I inherited in 1965.  The major pieces are 8 inches tall.  I am enclosing photo of the inlaid mother of pearl chop marks on the bottom of these pieces......Is it possible to translate and identify the maker and age of the chess set?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qianlong_Emperor

乾隆 was a Qing Dynasty emperor,

年 means year

and 製 can mean manufacture

https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?page=worddict&wdrst=1&wdqb=%E4%B9%BE%E9%9A%86%E5%B9%B4%E8%A3%BD

Or, per google it can mean Qianlong year system

https://translate.google.com/?sl=zh-CN&tl=en&text=%E4%B9%BE%E9%9A%86%E5%B9%B4%E8%A3%BD&op=translate

so, either way,  I'm assuming that means sometime between 1735-1796

Comment: thank you for the informed response . most useful and greatly appreciated